# How do you center CSS3 regardless of window size?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to center the following HTML and CSS3 so no matter what size the browser window is, the css will auto-format the shapes to where it will remain center at all times?

As you can see even in the code snippet window is re-sizes the menu buttons and moves them below each other like so:

```
_ _ _ _
_
```

When I am attempting to code it like this:

```
_ _ _ _ _
```

I have tried text align, padding changes etc.

Thoughts?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    background-color: #000;
}
.container {
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 90%;
}

/* general styles */
.menu, .menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.menu {
    height: 58px;
}
.menu li {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#292929, #252525);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#292929, #252525);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #292929), color-stop(100%, #252525));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#292929, #252525);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#292929, #252525);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#292929', endColorstr='#252525');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#292929', endColorstr='#252525')";
    background: linear-gradient(#292929, #252525);

    border-bottom: 2px solid #181818;
    border-top: 2px solid #303030;
    min-width: 160px;
}
.menu > li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.menu > li:first-child {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0;
}
.menu a {
    border-left: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: #808080;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Lucida Console';
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 54px;
    padding: 0 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* onhover styles */
.menu li:hover {
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#1c1c1c, #1b1b1b);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#1c1c1c, #1b1b1b);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #1c1c1c), color-stop(100%, #1b1b1b));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1c1c1c, #1b1b1b);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#1c1c1c, #1b1b1b);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1c1c1c', endColorstr='#1b1b1b');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1c1c1c', endColorstr='#1b1b1b')";
    background: linear-gradient(#1c1c1c, #1b1b1b);

    border-bottom: 2px solid #222222;
    border-top: 2px solid #1B1B1B;
}
.menu li:hover > a {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    border-left: 3px solid #C4302B;
    color: #C4302B;
}

/* submenu styles */
.submenu {
    left: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 0;

    -webkit-perspective: 400px;
    -moz-perspective: 400px;
    -ms-perspective: 400px;
    -o-perspective: 400px;
    perspective: 400px;
}
.submenu li {
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    transform: rotateY(90deg);

    -webkit-transition: opacity .4s, -webkit-transform .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .4s, -moz-transform .5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .4s, -ms-transform .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .4s, -o-transform .5s;
    transition: opacity .4s, transform .5s;
}
.menu .submenu li:hover a {
    border-left: 3px solid #454545;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.menu > li:hover .submenu, .menu > li:focus .submenu {
    max-height: 2000px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.menu > li:hover .submenu li, .menu > li:focus .submenu li {
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    -o-transform: none;
    transform: none;
}

/* CSS3 delays for transition effects */
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 50ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 50ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 50ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 50ms;
    transition-delay: 50ms;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 100ms;
    transition-delay: 100ms;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 150ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 150ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 150ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 150ms;
    transition-delay: 150ms;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 200ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 200ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 200ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 200ms;
    transition-delay: 200ms;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 250ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 250ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 250ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 250ms;
    transition-delay: 250ms;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(7) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 300ms;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(8) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 350ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 350ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 350ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 350ms;
    transition-delay: 350ms;
}

.submenu li:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 350ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 350ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 350ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 350ms;
    transition-delay: 350ms;
}
.submenu li:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 300ms;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}
.submenu li:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 250ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 250ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 250ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 250ms;
    transition-delay: 250ms;
}
.submenu li:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 200ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 200ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 200ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 200ms;
    transition-delay: 200ms;
}
.submenu li:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 150ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 150ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 150ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 150ms;
    transition-delay: 150ms;
}
.submenu li:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 100ms;
    transition-delay: 100ms;
}
.submenu li:nth-child(7) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 50ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 50ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 50ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 50ms;
    transition-delay: 50ms;
}
.submenu li:nth-child(8) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="author" content="Script Tutorials" />
        <title>Whirling dropdown menu | Script Tutorials</title>

        <!-- add styles -->
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="main" role="main">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#s1">Menu 1</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu b</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu c</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu d</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu e</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu f</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu g</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu h</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#s2">Menu 2</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu b</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu c</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu d</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu e</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu f</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu g</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu h</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu b</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu c</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu d</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu e</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu f</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu g</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu h</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.script-tutorials.com/whirling-dropdown-menu/">Back to tutorial</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

      <!-- Only used for Script Tutorial's Demo site. Please ignore and remove. -->
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="http://www.script-tutorials.com/assets/ads.js" async></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want it to never wrap?

Comment: This isn't a centering issue.

Comment: It is a width issue, if you want it to stay on the same line, something will have to give, most likely you will need to shrink things.

Comment: Yes that is what I am attempting to do a shrinking so everything stays center and functional is the link provided explain how to do this? Apologies learning as I go..

Comment: If you have a min-width set to 160px; and have 6, 6x160 = **960** I bet your pages breaks around 960px;

Comment: You will need to use media queries.

Comment: Best thing to do would be to set up media queries so that once the viewport gets below the point where all menu items are on the same line, you can change the padding/width/font-size etc. to make each menu item smaller. Also, I would suggest creating a completely different looking menu for mobile devices where the menu items stack vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

I removed **display: block; float: left;** from **.menu > li** and replaced it with **display: inline-block; margin-left: -0.3em;**

I then added **margin-left: 0;** to **.menu > li:first-child**

Finally, I added **text-align: center;** to **.menu**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    background-color: #000;
}
.container {
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 90%;
}

/* general styles */
.menu, .menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.menu {
    height: 58px;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu li {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#292929, #252525);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#292929, #252525);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #292929), color-stop(100%, #252525));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#292929, #252525);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#292929, #252525);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#292929', endColorstr='#252525');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#292929', endColorstr='#252525')";
    background: linear-gradient(#292929, #252525);

    border-bottom: 2px solid #181818;
    border-top: 2px solid #303030;
    min-width: 160px;
}
.menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -0.3em;
    position: relative;
}
.menu > li:first-child {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.menu a {
    border-left: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: #808080;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Lucida Console';
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 54px;
    padding: 0 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* onhover styles */
.menu li:hover {
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#1c1c1c, #1b1b1b);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#1c1c1c, #1b1b1b);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #1c1c1c), color-stop(100%, #1b1b1b));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1c1c1c, #1b1b1b);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#1c1c1c, #1b1b1b);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1c1c1c', endColorstr='#1b1b1b');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1c1c1c', endColorstr='#1b1b1b')";
    background: linear-gradient(#1c1c1c, #1b1b1b);

    border-bottom: 2px solid #222222;
    border-top: 2px solid #1B1B1B;
}
.menu li:hover > a {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    border-left: 3px solid #C4302B;
    color: #C4302B;
}

/* submenu styles */
.submenu {
    left: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 0;

    -webkit-perspective: 400px;
    -moz-perspective: 400px;
    -ms-perspective: 400px;
    -o-perspective: 400px;
    perspective: 400px;
}
.submenu li {
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    transform: rotateY(90deg);

    -webkit-transition: opacity .4s, -webkit-transform .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .4s, -moz-transform .5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .4s, -ms-transform .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .4s, -o-transform .5s;
    transition: opacity .4s, transform .5s;
}
.menu .submenu li:hover a {
    border-left: 3px solid #454545;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.menu > li:hover .submenu, .menu > li:focus .submenu {
    max-height: 2000px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.menu > li:hover .submenu li, .menu > li:focus .submenu li {
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    -o-transform: none;
    transform: none;
}

/* CSS3 delays for transition effects */
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 50ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 50ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 50ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 50ms;
    transition-delay: 50ms;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 100ms;
    transition-delay: 100ms;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 150ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 150ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 150ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 150ms;
    transition-delay: 150ms;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 200ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 200ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 200ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 200ms;
    transition-delay: 200ms;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 250ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 250ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 250ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 250ms;
    transition-delay: 250ms;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(7) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 300ms;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(8) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 350ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 350ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 350ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 350ms;
    transition-delay: 350ms;
}

.submenu li:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 350ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 350ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 350ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 350ms;
    transition-delay: 350ms;
}
.submenu li:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 300ms;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}
.submenu li:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 250ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 250ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 250ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 250ms;
    transition-delay: 250ms;
}
.submenu li:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 200ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 200ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 200ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 200ms;
    transition-delay: 200ms;
}
.submenu li:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 150ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 150ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 150ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 150ms;
    transition-delay: 150ms;
}
.submenu li:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 100ms;
    transition-delay: 100ms;
}
.submenu li:nth-child(7) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 50ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 50ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 50ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 50ms;
    transition-delay: 50ms;
}
.submenu li:nth-child(8) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="author" content="Script Tutorials" />
        <title>Whirling dropdown menu | Script Tutorials</title>

        <!-- add styles -->
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="main" role="main">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#s1">Menu 1</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu b</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu c</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu d</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu e</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu f</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu g</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu h</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#s2">Menu 2</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu b</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu c</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu d</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu e</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu f</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu g</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu h</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu b</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu c</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu d</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu e</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu f</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu g</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu h</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.script-tutorials.com/whirling-dropdown-menu/">Back to tutorial</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

      <!-- Only used for Script Tutorial's Demo site. Please ignore and remove. -->
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="http://www.script-tutorials.com/assets/ads.js" async></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This accomplished what I needed. I would like to re-size based on screen size and such, however this is sufficient you are awesome :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

USE CSS

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    background-color: #000;
}
.container {
    margin: 30px auto;
    max-width: 1040px;
}

/* general styles */
.menu, .menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.menu {
    height: 58px;
}
.menu li {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#292929, #252525);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#292929, #252525);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #292929), color-stop(100%, #252525));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#292929, #252525);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#292929, #252525);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#292929', endColorstr='#252525');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#292929', endColorstr='#252525')";
    background: linear-gradient(#292929, #252525);

    border-bottom: 2px solid #181818;
    border-top: 2px solid #303030;
    min-width: 160px;
}
.menu > li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.menu > li:first-child {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0;
}
.menu a {
    border-left: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: #808080;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Lucida Console';
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 54px;
    padding: 0 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* onhover styles */
.menu li:hover {
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#1c1c1c, #1b1b1b);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#1c1c1c, #1b1b1b);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #1c1c1c), color-stop(100%, #1b1b1b));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1c1c1c, #1b1b1b);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#1c1c1c, #1b1b1b);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1c1c1c', endColorstr='#1b1b1b');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1c1c1c', endColorstr='#1b1b1b')";
    background: linear-gradient(#1c1c1c, #1b1b1b);

    border-bottom: 2px solid #222222;
    border-top: 2px solid #1B1B1B;
}
.menu li:hover > a {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    border-left: 3px solid #C4302B;
    color: #C4302B;
}

/* submenu styles */
.submenu {
    left: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 0;

    -webkit-perspective: 400px;
    -moz-perspective: 400px;
    -ms-perspective: 400px;
    -o-perspective: 400px;
    perspective: 400px;
}
.submenu li {
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    transform: rotateY(90deg);

    -webkit-transition: opacity .4s, -webkit-transform .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .4s, -moz-transform .5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .4s, -ms-transform .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .4s, -o-transform .5s;
    transition: opacity .4s, transform .5s;
}
.menu .submenu li:hover a {
    border-left: 3px solid #454545;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.menu > li:hover .submenu, .menu > li:focus .submenu {
    max-height: 2000px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.menu > li:hover .submenu li, .menu > li:focus .submenu li {
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    -o-transform: none;
    transform: none;
}

/* CSS3 delays for transition effects */
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 50ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 50ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 50ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 50ms;
    transition-delay: 50ms;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 100ms;
    transition-delay: 100ms;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 150ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 150ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 150ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 150ms;
    transition-delay: 150ms;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 200ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 200ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 200ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 200ms;
    transition-delay: 200ms;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 250ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 250ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 250ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 250ms;
    transition-delay: 250ms;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(7) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 300ms;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu li:nth-child(8) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 350ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 350ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 350ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 350ms;
    transition-delay: 350ms;
}

.submenu li:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 350ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 350ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 350ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 350ms;
    transition-delay: 350ms;
}
.submenu li:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 300ms;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}
.submenu li:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 250ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 250ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 250ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 250ms;
    transition-delay: 250ms;
}
.submenu li:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 200ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 200ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 200ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 200ms;
    transition-delay: 200ms;
}
.submenu li:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 150ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 150ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 150ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 150ms;
    transition-delay: 150ms;
}
.submenu li:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 100ms;
    transition-delay: 100ms;
}
.submenu li:nth-child(7) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 50ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 50ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 50ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 50ms;
    transition-delay: 50ms;
}
.submenu li:nth-child(8) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```